# Conservation law(s) of chemical reaction $\rm A \longrightarrow B + 2C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chemistry

I am trying to find the conservation law for the following chemical reaction:

$$\rm A \longrightarrow B + 2C$$

where:

- A converts into $B$ and $C$ at a rate $k (k>0)$.
- $[A]_0$, $[B]_0$, $[C]_0$ are initial concentrations of $A$, $B$ and $C$
- $[B]_0$ and $[C]_0$ are initially $\rm 0\  M$.

I am thinking the conservation laws are:

- $[B] + [A] = [A]_0$
- $[C] + 2[A] = 2[A]_0$

Am I correct? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You are given with, $$-\dfrac{d[A]_0}{dt} = \dfrac{d[B]_0}{dt} = \dfrac12\dfrac{d[C]_0}{dt}$$ and $$\dfrac{d[A]_0}{dt} = -k[A]$$

Comment: @A---B Each $[X]_0$ and $[X]$ in your comment should read $[X]_t$.

Comment: "Am I correct?" Yes, these are the two elementary conserved quantities. From them, one can deduce tons of other conserved quantities, of course, such as $3[A]_t+[B]_t+[C]_t$.

Comment: I don't necessarily understand what you are looking for. There are any number of conservation laws you could construct for this reaction. What are you looking to do with these conservation laws?

Comment: @Tyberius But, as is always the case in chemical reactions, all these conserved quantities can be reduced to the combinations of a finite number, for example, combinations of [B]+[A] and [C]+2[A]. No real objection here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a, b, c : \mathbb R_0^+ \to \mathbb R_0^+$ be the time-varying amounts of chemical species $A, B, C$, respectively. The chemical reaction $A \to B + 2 C$ is modeled by the following system of $3$ coupled linear ODEs

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \begin{bmatrix} a (t)\\ b (t)\\ c (t) \end{bmatrix} = \kappa \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a (t)\\ b (t)\\ c (t) \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\kappa > 0$ is the rate at which species $A$ decays. The matrix above, which we henceforth denote by $\mathrm M$, is rank-$1$. Thus, the left and right null spaces of $\rm M$ are $2$-dimensional. Via Gaussian elimination, we quickly conclude that the **left** null space of $\rm M$ is parametrized as follows

$$\left\{ \gamma_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} + \gamma_2 \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix} : \gamma_1, \gamma_2 \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

Let the initial conditions be $a (0) =: a_0$ and $b (0) = c (0) = 0$. Choosing different values for $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, we obtain different conservation laws. For example,

- $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2) = (1, 0)$ produces $\dot a + \dot b = 0$. Integrating, we obtain $a (t) + b (t) = a_0$.
- $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2) = (0, 1)$ produces $2 \dot a + \dot c = 0$. Integrating, we obtain $2 a (t) + c (t) = 2 a_0$.
- $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2) = (2,-1)$ produces $2 \dot b - \dot c = 0$. Integrating, we obtain $2 b (t) - c (t) = 0$.
- $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2) = (1, 1)$ produces $3 \dot a + \dot b + \dot c = 0$. Integrating, we obtain $3 a (t) + b (t) + c (t) = 3 a_0$.

The general conservation law is, thus,

$$(\gamma_1 + 2 \gamma_2) \, a (t) + \gamma_1 b (t) + \gamma_2 c (t) = (\gamma_1 + 2 \gamma_2) \, a_0$$

and the solution of the system of ODEs is

$$\begin{bmatrix} a (t)\\ b (t)\\ c (t) \end{bmatrix} = \left( \mathrm I_3 + \left( 1 - \exp( -\kappa t) \right) \mathrm M \right) \begin{bmatrix} a_0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} = a_0 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix} + a_0 \left( 1 - \exp( -\kappa t) \right) \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 1\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: There are more conserved quantities than $3a+b+c$. Actually what we have here is a question more advanced than an "answer". This should be the opposite, right?